# sink and sing...not rhyming but what is it called for rhyming the end of two words

Tags: terminology, rhymes

What is the definition of reverse rhyming of words where the last few letters of two words are different rather than the beginning letters of two rhyming words.  For example: cow, cop, coy, cot, con.  Or another example: beef, been beep, beer, bees.  So rather than rhyming sing with king, I'd use sing and sink for reverse rhyming....if that makes sense?  I know there's a term for that, but I don't know what it's called?  :( Help?

Comment: _Rhyme_ is at the end of a word. _Assonance_ is the same thing, at the beginning of a word. Both are used in poetry. Take a look at Old English poetry; it used assonance instead of rhyme.

Comment: Rhyming per se has nothing to do with "the last few letters", or any letters. It is about sounds, not spelling. Perhaps you mean to ask about rhyming all but the final sound (consonant sound)? But your title says just the opposite of that. As it stands now, the question is unclear, to me at least.

Comment: @John Hm! In at least Spanish philology, *assonance* means just the vowels rhyme, and this is the normal way to rhyme in Spanish; see anything by Lorca etc. They call the Italian (now also English) style rhyming *consonance*. Is this a false friend or alternate  definition? Tolkien called alliterative poetry *head-rhyme* to distinguish it from the newer *tail-rhyme*. Both are found in *Gawain*, with the tail-rhyme in the "wheel". Shippey calls the *fail/fall* pattern alliterating at both ends but changing medial vowel "alliterative assonance" or the "*Macbeth* device".

Comment: "He will not see me stopping here/To watch his woods fill up with snow...The only other sound’s the sweep/Of easy wind and downy flake." Assonance. Beautiful in the hands of a master like Frost.

Comment: Indeed. I once did [a phonetic transcription of a Frost poem](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/What50Said.pdf) for my intro etymology course.

Comment: The technical terms, following Bolinger, are _rime_ and _assonance_, which are strictly defined. The _assonance_ of a monosyllabic word is the initial consonant or consonant cluster; basically, everything up to the vowel. The _rime_ is the nuclear vowel, plus the final consonant or cluster. Since rimes have two components (15 or so English nuclear vowels times quite a lot of possible syllable codas equals around 480 possible rimes in English). However, there are fewer than 100 possible assonances. [More details are available](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/#mono), for anyone interested.

Comment: @JohnLawler - very cool! Unfortunately I could understand less than 20% of those words. But very interesting.

Comment: @Drew There is such a thing as an [eye-rhyme](http://literarydevices.net/rhyme/), however, which is entirely about spelling.

Comment: Some may not understand the question, which does **not** mean they should vote to close!

Comment: @JohnLawler There seems to be more than one definition of 'assonance' and those are not even closely related. https://www.google.com/webhp?tab=ww#q=define+assonance

Comment: Using adjacent words that begin with the same letter is called _alliteration_.

Comment: So, is anyone going to make their comment(s) into an Answer?

Comment: @choster: Yes, I figured someone would say something similar. That's precisely why I explicitly added "*per se*". **Anything** that repeats or reflects in some sense can be said to *rhyme* in some sense. Consider, for example, the well known sentence "*History does not repeat; it rhymes.*

Comment: @Kris: As I said, I follow Bolinger's terms of _rime_ and _assonance_; they're the standard technical terms for this. Dictionaries, of course, report **all** the meanings of a word; that's why I specified Bolinger.

Comment: @JohnLawler Perhaps you will wish to edit [this then](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assonance): “Assonance is the repetition of vowel sounds to create internal rhyming within phrases or sentences, and together with alliteration and consonance serves as one of the building blocks of verse. Assonance is a rhyme, the identity of which depends merely on the vowel sounds. Thus, an assonance is merely a syllabic resemblance.” Those are the senses of *assonance, consonance,* and *alliteration* as I previously understood them.

Comment: I am not responsible for Wikipedia, and Wikipedia is not responsible for me. Nor am I responsible for, or to, your prior understandings. As I said (twice now) these are the terms I use, as I use them, professionally.

Answer (score 3):

[***Alliteration***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/alliteration) is the matching of first letters or sounds in closely connected words.

> NOUN
>
> [MASS NOUN]
>
> The occurrence of the same letter **or sound** at the beginning of adjacent or closely connected words:

In English verse, the final words of adjacent lines are closely connected by the practice of rhyming. The expression *reverse rhyming* is quite an intuitive guess for this special kind of  "[***assonance***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/assonance)".

> NOUN
>
> [MASS NOUN]
>
> Resemblance of sound between syllables of nearby words,

Comment: As the definition shows, it's all about letters, not sounds. In fact, the very name refers to 'letter' not sound. How's the relevant to the context?

Comment: Unfortunately, English is often too flexible to accommodate our technical analysis. Along with OED, I appreciate the distinction between the technical definitions and the way Everyman thinks about it. The OP's description is not EXACTLY alliteration or assonance in a technical sense, but those words strike pretty close to the mark. If there is a better word to describe the phenomenon, I'll use it, but I haven't found it yet.